# Skinning CXTPButton doesn't work in Codejock 16.4.0

Tags: c++, mfc

We have a large application using Codejock (C++, MFC, VisualStudio 2012). We use SkinFramework - the user can choose between many skins. We will soon release a new version, and we have upgraded Codejock to 16.4.0. But we noticed that the skinning of the Codejock buttons doesn't work in the new version. Is this a bug? Or did we miss something?

We use icons for certain buttons, so some of our buttons are CXTPButton, some ordinary CButton. With our previous Codejock version (15.3.1), both type of buttons looked the same. For example if we skin it with Vista.cjstyles/NormalBlack2.INI:

[image: Vista in 15.3.1]

But with the new version, CButton:s get skinned OK, but not CXTPButton:s:

[image: Vista in 16.4.0]

It looks even worse with other skins - take WinXP.Luna.cjstyles/NormalBlue.INI:

[image: Luna in 16.4.0]

(We have tried all possible combinations of settings for the CXTPButton - with calls to SetUseVisualStyle/SetBorderStyle/SetTheme. The appearance changes, but the button never gets skinned.)

This only happens when skinning with CXTPSkinManager::LoadSkin(). If we use the built-in themes (set with CXTPPaintManager::SetTheme()), everything looks OK.

Is there some new call that must be made? Or some default setting that has changed in Codejock? We just want all buttons to look the same. We are running out of time - we would be very grateful for some help!

/Anders from Sweden

Comment: Have you also tried asking on [the CodeJock forum](http://forum.codejock.com/default.asp)?

Comment: Yes I have - and sent it to CJ support. They can take very long to answer, though, so I thought I should post here too. But this time I got a quick answer from CJ! :-) (See below.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a quick answer from Codejock. This is a bug in the latest release (16.4.0). But it has been found and will be fixed in the next beta/release. I got the files that have been updated, so I could recompile the libraries. And now everything works! :-)

(The bug affected more than buttons. For example could menu backgrounds lose their skinning. If this happends to you, just contact Codejock to get the fix. Or send me a message, and I'll send you the files.)

Answer (score -1):

Codejock is now on version 17 with more bug fixes

Comment: Welcome to the site! [Please use Answers exclusively to answer the question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/92107). To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have [sufficient reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). In the meantime, please do not use answers to post comments.